# How to change type of the fact parameter (String to double) for correct comparison in Drools?

Tags: drools

I use Drools template (.drt file) where I want to compare whether some parameter of a fact is less or greater than some double value. But the fact parameter is a String representation (that object's parameter are all string types). So I try to parse it to double like this:
when

```
$pile: Resource(Double.valueOf(amount) < 30.0) //or next
//$pile: Resource(Double.parseDouble(amount) < 30.0)//both don't work in drt
```

then
...
The problem is that in other rules this works normally, but here gives exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error evaluating constraint
>   'Double.parseDouble(name) == Double.parseDouble("5.0")' in [Rule
>   "Calculation of pile driver's machine hours_5" in pileDriverRates.xls]

In drl files this sort of comparison works fine, maybe there must be another method to use in .drt files?
I use intellij idea, Ubuntu
My pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
      <version>${runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
      <version>${runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
      <version>${runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-test</artifactId>
  <version>${runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

template header

```
code
name
weightMin
weightMax
boom
```

package rules.drivenPiles;

```
import com.sample.Work;
import com.sample.Resource;
import com.sample.ResourceParameter;

dialect "mvel"
```

template "Choose crane boom"

```
rule "Choose crane boom_@{row.rowNumber}"
salience -20
    activation-group "second"

when
    $pile: Resource(Double.parseDouble(amount) > @{weightMin}, Double.parseDouble(amount) < @{weightMax})
then
    String boomLength = "@{boom}";
```

It gives an error, but when I make when statement as:
when

```
$pile: Resource(amount == "50")
```

It fires the rule (if amount is 50, of corse, I check it manually).
So my guess was that parsing doesn't work in .drt files, but my friend tells me that he made in .drt files lines like Double.valueOf(amount) == 50.0 and it worked.

Comment: It's hard to be sure, obviously, but `Double.parseDouble(name)` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: As I see now after a while, this problem is engaged, as I may suppose, with rule evaluation and rule execution stages. 
1) Because first I create a rule in 1.drt file:
Resource item = new Resource();
Here I don't put "value" parameter
2) Then in 2.drl file I add "value" parameter:
modify($pile){setAmount("20")}
3) Then in the above "Choose crane boom" template I try to see that amount that must be 20

Comment: Oh yeah, Andrew, that was my fault. Now it says: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error evaluating constraint 'Double.parseDouble(amount) == Double.parseDouble("0.20")' in [Rule "Choose crane boom_56" in truckCraneBoom.xls]
So there is a problem with "amount" parameter
As you may see I manually had put "20". But drools doesn't know about stage 2, when I modified "amount" parameter. At least this is my conclusion, because when I set "amount" parameter as "20" at stage 1) (in the comment above when I create item object) - there's no error

Comment: There's no error and it parses both sides of fact as it should do.
So the problem is with the evaluation stage. How can I make drools know about setting "amount" parameter from null to "20"? As you've seen I used "modify" but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with rule evaluation and rule execution stages in Drools. I tried to describe it in comments but I think it has completely messed up the whole picture so I created the new question:
[How to control rule evaluation (or rule execution) stages in Drools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559828/how-to-control-rule-evaluation-or-rule-execution-stages-in-drools)
So if you meet an exception while trying to change fact's parameter from Double to String or something like that - this may be one of the reasons